# Use the number of characters obtained in a sentence of the regular expression in the string replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, ecmascript-5

I'm doing a Markdown parser as part of a study on regular expressions, I would like to use the number of characters obtained on a stretch of expression, as string replacement base, for example :

```
# Title
## Title
```

the first title will be added an H1 because I only have a #, the second will be added an H2 because I have two # .

And I would use the amount of stretch of the characters is the # Regular expression to replace a string, for example :

```
markdown.replace ( /(\#+) *( +)/ig, "<h?>$2</hr?>");
```

Where the ? would be the amount found by the expression # .

My entry is somewhat confusing, but this was the best way I found to explain the situation .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution, replace can recieve an function, so I can do anything I need, check my solution:

```
        markdown = markdown.replace(/(\#+) *(.+)/ig, function(exp, n1, n2){
            size = n1.length;
            return "<h"+size+">"+n2+"</h"+size+">";
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant "count" with regex.

Why not just do

```
markdown.replace ( /(\#\#) *( +)/ig, "<h2>$2</h2>")
    .replace ( /(\#) *( +)/ig, "<h1>$2</h1>");
```

Comment: You are right, I cant count with regex, but I can do the magic with a javascript function, I found a interesting solution, check my Answer.